# How to select a div from Ajax Response using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, prototype

I am trying the following code, but still I didn't get any success.

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
    url,
    {
        method: 'post',
        onException: function (xhr, e)
        {
            alert('Exception : ' + e);
        },
        onComplete: function (xhr)
        {
            var myHtml = xhr.responseText;

            // alert(myHtml);

            var myContent = $(myHtml).select("div#product-options-wrapper");

            alert(myContent);
        }
 });
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: does the var myHtml already contain a '.' or a '#' at the beginning of the string? Could you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: The var myHtml contains whole page as response. From where I need to extract a div with id **#product-options-wrapper**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the HTML is a string - like others have mentioned try adding it to a container div and then getting the elements you want out of it. FYI the `select()` will return an array of elements that match the selector so if you only want the specific `<div>` use the `down()` method which will return the first one.

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
    url,
    {
        method: 'post',
        onException: function (xhr, e)
        {
            alert('Exception : ' + e);
        },
        onComplete: function (xhr)
        {
            var myHtml = xhr.responseText;

            // alert(myHtml);

            var myContent = new Element('div').update(myHtml);

            myContent = myContent.down("div#product-options-wrapper");

            alert(myContent);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

myHtml is still a string object ... I guess you should add it to the DOM then you can select whatever

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
url,
{
    method: 'post',
    onException: function (xhr, e)
    {
        alert('Exception : ' + e);
    },
    onComplete: function (xhr)
    {
        var myHtml = xhr.responseText;

        // alert(myHtml);

        /***** append your html to any container in the document ***/

        var myContent = $(myHtml).select("div#product-options-wrapper");

        alert(myContent);
    }
```

});